# Woocommerce: set max number of ordered products per month

Tags: php, woocommerce

I want to set a limit for number of orders a customer can make per month in **WooCommerce**. The limit is individual for each customer, and is based on the number of products where the customer is "Post-Owner", meaning that they have created the product.

**Example:** customer has created 2 products, then they can order 2 products per month.

This check needs to be done in the Cart page each time it is refreshed or an item is added, and if the condition fails the "Checkout" button will be disabled and a message displayed.

**The condition is:**

1. (Count "Products" WHERE "Post-Owner" IS "Current User") THEN
2. (Count "Orders" WHERE "Order Date" is "Current Month) THEN
3. (Count "Products" in Cart) THEN
4. IF Order_Count + Product_Count <= Current_User_Products THEN Proceed
5. ELSE Disable Checkout button and Show a Message to the user.

I am a total newbie to **WooCommerce** so I would appreciate if you could provide useful code snippets.

Comment: Post owner means product owner ? Then who is buyer and who is seller ?

Comment: This shop is for renting products between users. In this scenario, each member of the shop can upload products they want to rent out. They can then also consume products from other members. So the transaction is made from customer to customer.

Comment: Is the first count monthly also? Or absolute?

Comment: The first count is absolute.